# Recreational Mathematics title search

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics

I once read part of a book on recreational mathematics that told a variety of stories. A central part of each story was a piece of non-trivial, and very interesting mathematics: the sofa moving problem, and finite projective planes are two topics that I am sure it covered.

My question: what is the title of this book?

Comment: This seems like very little information to go on. Do you remember anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well here's a guess:  Another Fine Math You've Gotten Me Into, by Ian Stewart.

http://books.google.com/books?id=ZfK7AQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&vq=Sofa&output=html_text&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0

Comment: That's the one. Thanks very much